# Avoid html formatting when adding elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'd like to add an element to the HTML DOM using this small function below:

```js
function add() {
  var text = "this is a <b>formatted</b> test"
  var element = "<div style='background: red;'>\
                    <a href='#'>" + text + "</a>\
                  </div>"
  elem.innerHTML += element
}

add();
```

What I got so far:

```html
<div id="elem"></div>

<p style="margin-top: 10%">This is what it should look like (of course no blanks):</p>

<div style="background: red;">
    <a href='#'>
      this is a < b >formatted< / b > test
    </a>
</div>
```

By changing the `text` property the text on this element can be changed. But however, HTML attributes are still formatted instead of just displaying them as plain text. (In the example above the "formatted"-word gets bold)`

> How can I avoid this text-formatting without massively changing my "add"-function?

I can not change the code into

```js
elem.innerText += element
```

because this will kill all the style attributes (like `background-color`, etc)

Comment: _'By changing the "innerText"'_ - what you're obviously not doing: `elem.innerHTML += element` O.o

Comment: Because `elem.innerText` will kill the style-attributes! It's about the "text"-variable @Andreas

Comment: You just need to escape the HTML in the string. See [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](//stackoverflow.com/q/24816)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd set the `innerText` for the `a` only and append it to `elem` using JavaScript.

```js
function add() {
  var innerText = "this is a <b>formatted</b> test"
  
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', '#');
  a.innerText = innerText;
  
  var element = "<div style='background: red;'></div>"
  elem.innerHTML += element;
  elem.appendChild(a);
}


add()
```

```html
What I got so far:
<div id="elem"></div>



<p style="margin-top: 10%">This is what it should look like (of course no blanks):</p>

<div style="background: red;">
    <a href='#'>
      this is a < b >formatted< / b > test
    </a>
</div>
```

Or using jQuery's constructor (`$("<a>", {text: innerText, href: '#'})`) which would make it simpler.

```js
function add() {
  var innerText = "this is a <b>formatted</b> test"
  
  var a = $("<a>", {text: innerText, href: '#'});
  
  var element = "<div style='background: red;'></div>"
  $(elem).html(element);
  $(elem).append(a);
}


add()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
What I got so far:
<div id="elem"></div>



<p style="margin-top: 10%">This is what it should look like (of course no blanks):</p>

<div style="background: red;">
    <a href='#'>
      this is a < b >formatted< / b > test
    </a>
</div>
```

But...

## An escaping problem

Your problem is actually a problem of escaping those strings. Using jQuery, this can be achieved as below.

No line past `var text = ...` is changed. `elem.innerHTML += element` remains.

```js
function escapeHTML(htmlToEscape) {
  return $("<span>").text(htmlToEscape).html();
}
function add() {
  var text = escapeHTML("this is a <b>formatted</b> test");
  var element = "<div style='background: red;'>\
                    <a href='#'>" + text + "</a>\
                  </div>"
  elem.innerHTML += element
}

add()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
What I got so far:
<div id="elem"></div>

<p style="margin-top: 10%">This is what it should look like (of course no blanks):</p>

<div style="background: red;">
    <a href='#'>
      this is a < b >formatted< / b > test
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `xmp` tag

```js
function add() {
  var innerText = "this is a <xmp><b></xmp>formatted<xmp></b></xmp> test"
  var element = "<div style='background: red;'>\
                    <a href='#'>" + innerText + "</a>\
                  </div>"
  elem.innerHTML += element
}


add()
```

```css
xmp {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Comment: you can add class to `a` to add styles

Comment: I don't want to add styles, I want to avoid that the XMP tags are changing those!

Answer (score 0):

## Add Spaces + Reduce Kerning (-2px)

I think you guys are WAY over-thinking it. I'm still pretty new to *writing* code, but I've been building Wikis and other educational materials as I go along (because teaching is the most efficient way for me to learn anything).

I'm currently working on a Wiki explaining the differences between Markdown and HTML as markup languages, and in order to display tags/elements without actually applying them, I used a classic Graphic Design trick that makes working with separate fonts/font sizes in-line possible without creating new objects:

#### Adjust your Kerning, or in HTML/CSS: Your *Letter-Spacing*

So in my HTML+CSS document I'm using for comparison to Markdown I have two examples I'll cut down for you to copy and paste into whatever you're working on.

### In-Line Style Insertion:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<body>
    <style>
    .mainBody {
        background-color: #464747;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    </style>

<div class="mainBody">
    <span style="letter-spacing: -2px";>< b ></span>The reduced letter spacing perfectly removes the spaces between the characters in the bold tags above and below this line.<span style="letter-spacing: -2px";>< / b ></span>
</div>
```

### Multi-Line Style Insertion

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<body>
    <style>
    .mainBody {
        background-color: #464747;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    </style>

<div class="mainBody">
    <span style="letter-spacing: -2px";>
        < b >
    </span>

    The reduced letter spacing perfectly removes the spaces between the characters in the bold tags above and below this line.

    <span style="letter-spacing: -2px";>
        < / b >
    </span>
</div>
```

I have *hardcore* ADHD, so I need to use the multi-line method to make everything as easy to read as possible or I get lost immediately, but regardless of which one you use, the end result looks like this:

[HTML Kerning](https://static.wixstatic.com/media/40adf8_310af89ac3244f0c81057a56add8572f%7Emv2.png)

Hope this helps!